# How to encourage tag creators to edit tag wiki as well?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Some users create tags while adding question; some are highly useful and some are simply meaningless. Do SE have any mechanism to encourage users to add tag wiki as well, on creating tags?

Esp. see this question [In conference review process, what do “author response” and “author notification” mean?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3022/in-conference-review-process-what-do-author-response-and-author-notification) What actually the tags  ([wording](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/wording/info)) ([dates](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/dates/info)) ([call](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/call/info)) mean?

So, if the tag creator him(her)self propose a tag wiki, it is good for the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to "encourage" a tag creator to edit the tag wiki. However, you can retag the question, by removing the tags that either do not make sense or are not explained.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty common problem on the main SO site as well; people tag questions with seemingly ridiculous tags in the hopes of... well, I'm really not sure, but I guess they think that adding weird tags increases the chance they'll get an answer. There isn't really much we can do for these people, since they clearly didn't search to see other related stuff and then read the instructions next to the tag box that state to enter related tags. Not much we can do for those users.